# Calculation puzzle 008

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

What is x?

```
-----
| 22 |
----------
| 34 | 23 |
----------
| 57 |
-----

-----
| 43 |
----------
| 78 | 29 |
----------
| 16 |
-----

-----
| 52 |
----------
| 94 | 28 |
----------
| 35 |
-----

-----
| 62 |
----------
| 71 | x  |
----------
| 23 |
-----
```

There is a connection between the numbers. The same connection applies to all four parts and then we can find x.

I tried to do it, but couldn't solve. In the first one, 22+23+57=112 and 34*3=102, so 112-10=102. This method doesn't apply to the others. Added altogether to no avail. Multiplied digits, still no answer.

> The answer shown on the booklet is 21.

Source: The question is asked in YTUYOS 2017 booklet A, question no: 57. These are the questions asked in university entrance exam for international students in Turkey. These types of questions should not take more than 2 minutes to solve and generally they do have only one answer. In case they have more than one then the question is cancelled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is indeed:

> **21**

This is because, simply:

> The number on the right is the sum of all of the digits in the three left-hand boxes:
>
>  (2 + 2) + (3 + 4) + (5 + 7) = 23
>  (4 + 3) + (7 + 8) + (1 + 6) = 29
>  (5 + 2) + (9 + 4) + (3 + 5) = 28
>
>  and thus:
>
>  (6 + 2) + (7 + 1) + (2 + 3) = 21

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't think that way when I was trying to solve it. Good approach, I appreciate it.